# Shared Application

Tags: c#, .net, iis, entity-framework-4.1, domain-driven-design

I am creating an application to be accessed by multiple clients, but
each customer will have a different database, only access the
same application in IIS, I'm using DDD, C # and MvC3 and Entity Framework 4.1 CF. Does anyone have any example or an idea of how best to configure the connection string
specific to each client?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to identify whether it's a database per client (machine?), user identity authenticating, or some other identifier.  For example, if it's per account, then two machines may be able to authenticate as that account and get the same storage.

Once you have that identifier, you'll need a master table somewhere with a map of account to database connection string.  You'll probably also want to cache that table in memory to avoid two db roundtrips on every request.

That global configuration information is typically stored in a database.  You could go as simple as a file but that would cause problems if you ever wanted to scale out your front end servers, so common storage is best.